# Local vs remote mobile web app performance characteristics

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-applications, mobile, client-side

Can I assume client-side performance characteristics (javascript, css, memory) to be the same for a local web app (e.g. phonegap) and a remote web app (e.g. mobile browser)?

Comment: Define performance please.

Comment: FPS, painting, rendering, style recalculations, garbage collection - general responsiveness of the web app I guess is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are some differences at least for iOs.

There you will have a better performance within the browser compared to the installed app. In iOs there is a faster javascript engine enable in the safari, but not in the webview.

At Android there is a differnce too:
The user will use chrome, but the embedded webkit in android is older the webkit from chrome. There will be more bugs and a worse performance in android.

But the differences are mostly not that big.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe to assume that the characteristics will operate in a similar fashion between mobile web and a hybrid app developed using Phonegap.  Phonegap is nothing more than a shell with a webview that houses the files locally and provides APIs to interface with native device features.

Comment: Yes and No. In theory you are right. But there are some differences between the browser and the embedded webview.